# How we can Pass multiple argument in sonar Lint

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

logger.debug("This is completed detail of Shipping" + Price + orderId + ProductId + Country+ deliveryDate);

getting the error : "use the built-in formatting to construct this argument"
2nd argument is not in use
3nd argument is not in use
4nd argument is not in use
5nd argument is not in use

Comment: If this is SLF4J or Log4J 2, use place holders. For instance: `logger.debug("This is completed detail of Shipping {} {} {} {} {}", Price, orderId, ProductId, Country, deliveryDate);`. Each `{}` must have a value after the message. You can also add an additional argument for an exception.

Comment: Thanks its working fine